# What is a Bi-Analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to know what the definition of a Bi-analytic function is. I have tried looking it up online, but all I am able to find are research papers/books on the theory of bi-analytic functions. Can anyone please give a simple definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ and $V$ are two open subsets of the complex plane, and $f$ is a function from $U$ to $V$, we say that $f$ is bi-analytic (or bi-holomorphic) if it is analytic (holomorphic) and bijective.
(So, implicitly, it's inverse is holomorphic.)

Comment: so it is similar to a homeomorphism, except that here $f$ is also differentiable, whereas homeomorphism requires $f$ to be just continuous

Comment: Yes!  In a homeomorphism $f$ and its inverse are required to be continuous; here we require that $f$ and it's inverse are (complex-)differentiable.  So a bi-holomorphic function is a special kind of homeomorphism.

Comment: To check that a function is bi-holomorphic you can simply check that it is bijective and holomorphic, because the holomorphicity of its inverse follows automatically;
In the same way, if $U$ and $V$ are two open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, then you can check that $f:U\to V$ is a homeomorphism by checking that $f$ is bijective and continuous, because continuity of its inverse follows automatically from the Invariance of Domain Theorem.